# Does a belt count as a garment?

Tags: halacha, clothing

During a hectic work week I have been known to leave my belt in my pants and put my pants on with the belt simultaneously. But is the belt consider another garment? And if so, would it be a violation of putting on [two garments at once](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16899/wearing-clothes-backwards-or-inside-out/16906#16906)?

Comment: It should be noted that this is not an actual biblical or rabbinic prohibition. It is merely based on a supposed statement of the Arizal that doing this can cause forgetfulness of Torah. Even if this were true it is not at all clear that this is a prohibition.

Comment: Since this is not a halcha, psak is impossible; either it causes it or does not cause it, and no one has any way of really knowing what was intended by the first kabbalists who stated this unless their original statement happened to clarify.

Comment: Avnet of the Kohen Gadol was one of the Sheva begadim

Answer (score -1):

Seemingly being that in the Torah the avnet which was the sash or belt that the kohen would wear is called one of the BEGADIM

However at the same time I can tell u that since the only purpose of the belt is for the pants maybe they are considered one piece.

Comment: Sorry, so what is it? A garment or not?

Comment: @mbloch, this is not a site for _p'sak_; an answer that cites arguments to support one of the possibilities in the question is perfectly valid even if it is not decisive, so an answer that cites arguments in both directions is, too, no?

Comment: Yes I agree :)   .

Comment: @msh210 fair enough !

Comment: @msh210 An answer that cites sources in both directions, yes. A post that just tells us the same doubt of the question is not. After reading this post I know nothing new. The question already was does it count as a separate garment for this issue or does the fact that they go together help. Restating the question is not an answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, this answers provides an *argument* for why the belt should be considered not a separate garment (namely, its sole purpose is for the pants, something the question didn't mention) and *evidence* that it's considered a separate garment (namely, its being listed as such in another context, something the question also didn't mention).

Comment: @msh210 How enlightening...