# wearing two hats at the same time-is that a probelem?

Tags: sources-mekorot, clothing, kippa-yarmulka, superstition, memory

I grew up hearing that if you put two hats or two yarmulkas at the same time that you could forget your learning- is there any source for this?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya daddy!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16899/759

Comment: its a problem for carrying in a reshus harbim lfi ashkanzim...

Comment: The tag description for 'superstition' reads: "A belief or way of behaving that is based on fear of the unknown and faith in magic or luck : a belief that certain events or things will bring good or bad luck." This question, proposing ill non naturalistic effects of a particular action qualifies by definition, and warrants the tag. You don't need to use the word to warrant the tag, just as a question about Parashat Noah, need not mention those words to warrant the tag; it just has to be a question...about parashat noah...

Comment: @sam only if it's both Shabbat and if there is no eruv. I don't see any problem doing this on a weekday ... other than, perhaps, losing your *seichel* (as OP mentioned) ... and a hat in a gale.

Comment: @mevaqesh, that the forgetfulness is caused by luck is perhaps the answer. I don't see it in the question. Would you also tag "superstition" the question "I heard that getting lots of concussions can make one forget his learning. Is there a source for that?"? I don't see how that's different from this question.

Comment: @msh210 Your sample question gives no reason to assume a non-naturalistic explanation. This one provides not the slightest shred of reason to assume a naturalistic explanation. This distinction seems fundamental. If you do not appreciate it, I don't think anything I say can convince you.

Comment: @mevaqesh, you're right: neither question gives any reason to assume any particular kind of explanation. So neither is about superstition (though, again, answers may be).

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If not, consider clarifying what additional information you want.

Answer (score 3):

The Magen Avaham (OH 2:3) references Shaar HaKavanot of R. Hayyim Vital which states that one should not put on two items of clothes at the same time, as it can make one forget:

> ויזהר מללבוש ב' מלבושים יחד בפעם א' כי קשה לשכחה (הכוונות)
>
> One should be careful not to don two garments together at one time, for it can cause forgetfulness (Shaar HaKavanot).

This could perhaps be read to mean that one should not wear two garments at the same time. It seems likely that this is the source of the idea that you heard.

However, it doesn't appear (to me) that this is the Magen Avraham's intent, since then one would never be able to wear more than one garment at a time! Rather, it appears that he refers to *donning* two garment simultaneously; not *wearing* the two simultaneously.

---

Of course as with most things, proving the negative is very difficult, there could always be some source somewhere about wearing two hats, rather than donning two garments, but this seems (to me) to be the likeliest explanation.

Comment: Hat tip to someone who confirmed for me that the ShHK is speaking about donning, not wearing.

Comment: Does he mean two **different** garments? So, if a t-shirt is already stuck inside my polo shirt, before putting this on, one has to remove the t-shirt? And what about putting your feet into both shoes at the same time? I can't do that, either?

Comment: @DanF Neither the Magen Avraham nor the ShHK say anything about the garments being different in type. | "so, if a t-shirt is already stuck inside my polo shirt, before putting this on, one has to remove the t-shirt" it is a medical concern; that a particular activity could affect your physical and mental well being. If, indeed, your medical guidelines comes from 16th century superstitions, then you might indeed want to avoid donning two shirts simultaneously. Regarding the simultaneous shoes, perhaps they arent included in the 'garment' rubric, as far as this belief.