# Is there a problem with wearing clothing inside-out for Purim?

Tags: halacha, clothing, purim

[In general](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16899/wearing-clothes-backwards-or-inside-out), one should not wear clothing inside-out, as per [Shulchan Aruch, OC 2:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&pgnum=36):

> ידקדק בחלוקו ללובשו כדרכו שלא יהפוך הפנימי לחוץ
>
> One should be particular with his cloak to wear it properly, that the inside not be flipped outside.

As the Magen Avraham explains (§3):

> ויראו התפירות המגונות
>
> And they will see the disgusting stitches

May one wear his clothing inside-out on Purim, as (a part of) his costume, where the whole point is that one should not be dressed as he normally is?

Comment: As Poskim abrogate (or, excuse) the issue of Lo Yilbash per Purim costumes, this would presumably be the same; especially since it’s not a *halachah* (in the legal sense of the word).

Comment: @Oliver Which is Deorayso! So it is clearly Kal Va Chomer.

Comment: @Oliver What about according to those who don’t excuse Lo Yilbash for Purim? While most rely on the Rema’s leniency, not everyone agrees.

Comment: @DonielF According to those you can also argue that only when one of the things that are *kasheh le’shikcha* are routinely done (e.g. “***ha’ragil** b’zeisim*”) it’d be a concern, not when it’s done for a joke. OTOH sticklers for ‘*dvarim ha’kashim le’shikcha*’ (R’ C. Kanievsky et al) might be sensitive even when done on Purim. But, being that actual laws are somewhat mitigated in the spirit of *simchas* Purim there’s ample room to be less sensitive to something of this nature.

Comment: Why don't you continue the quote of MA in Shu"A: "לחוץ. ויראו התפירות המגונות ויתגנה בעיני הבריות וכתב הט''ז שיש חילוק בין ת''ח לשאר אנשים דלת''ח אם לבש החלוק הפוכה צריך להפכה **אבל שאר אינשי דעלמא יזהר לכתחלה שלא ללבשה הפוכה ע''ש.**"

Comment: It might help you forget the difference between ארור המן and ברוך מרדכי

Comment: @Al Where do you see him say that? My copy of Magen Avraham is the same until וכתב הט״ז, at which point he instead discusses putting on two garments at the same time (apparently the same text that [Menachem has](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16906/)).

Comment: @Oliver According to the discussion cited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16899/), it seems that the connection between this halacha and forgetfulness is dubious at best.

Comment: cc @Heshy ^^^^^